# Huawei P8 Lite Android 5.0.1 Can not find class error

Tags: android, class, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services

I have a Huawei P8 Lite running Android 5.0.1 and when I try to run my project, I get bunch of errors in the logs:

```
I/art: Can not find class: Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPager;
I/art: Can not find class: Landroid/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter;
I/art: Can not find class: Lcom/example/user/myapp/utils/Utils;
I/art: Can not find class: Lcom/example/user/myapp/activities/HomeActivity$1;
I/art: Can not find class: Lcom/craftar/CraftARActivity;
I/art: Can not find class: Lcom/craftar/ImageRecognition$SetCollectionListener;
```

There are entries in the logs for every class that my app or the libraries that I imported use. The app works, except the CraftAR scanning activity, which seems weird to me, because the logs say that the app can't find any classes. Is there a factory problem with Huawei P8 Lite running Android 5.0.1? I have to mention that I ran the app on a same device, but with a different Android version (6.0) and everything works as expected.

Comment: Looks like this might be specific for this version of Android on the Huawei P8 Lite. I found some references to a similar error, they suggest updating the device to 5.0.1: https://github.com/AntennaPod/AntennaPod/issues/959

Comment: It already runs on 5.0.1, my post wrongly said it's running 5.0.